# Mostrar numero de checkbox selecionados levando em conta registros já existentes no banco de dados

Tags: php, jquery, script

Olá tenho um script que faz um update no banco de dados a cada vez que marco o checkbox sem que o cliente veja;

```
        <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('.check').click( function () { 
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
                    $.post("altera.php", { checado : '0', id: $(this).val() }, function () { 
                    }); 
                } else { 
                    $.post("altera.php", { checado : '1', id: $(this).val() }, function () { 

                    }); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

e outro que conta o numero de checkbox que o cliente já selecionou;

```
        var contador = function() {
        var n = $("input:checked").length;
        $(".checkcount").text((n === 0 ? "" : "Já foram selecionadas ") + n + (n === 1 ? " foto" : " fotos") + "" );
        };
        contador(); 
        $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click",contador);
```

o problema é que não consegui fazer com que esse segundo código leve em consideração o primeiro pois quando seleciono os checkbox na mesma página ele conta normal mas quando mudo de pagina ele mostra zerado pois não considera os checkbox que já foram marcados no banco de dados pelo primeiro código;

Comment: Tens alguma função no servidor que te dê o numero de checkbox selecionados? Senão podes pôr isso na session ou passar por url de página para página.

Comment: Eu faria seguindo o raciocínio do @Sergio, no retorno do seu `POST` você informa quantos registros estão selecionados no banco.

Comment: Obrigado, @Maicon a ideia seria no altera.php verificar a quantidade e retornar mas como eu faria isso eu não sei,

Comment: Consegui criar a session e ser atualizada a cada clique porem nao consigo usar essa session na conta do segundo script que verifica quantos já foram marcados; poderiam me ajudar;

Comment: @Sergio, criei a session e estou tentando usar da seguinte forma '   var banco = <?php echo $_SESSION['totalfotos']; ?>;
   var a = $("input:checked").length;
   
   if (banco === 0) {
    //alert ('zerado');
    var n = parseInt($("input:checked").length)- parseInt(banco);
   } else {
    //alert ('jatem');
    var n = parseInt($("input:checked").length) + parseInt(banco);
   }' mas ele sempre soma ao invez de so considerar que aquele numero é uma ja preseistente

Comment: @PauloJorge o que te dá `alert(banco + ' ' + typeof banco);`?

Comment: @Sergio eu fiz o seguinte após a linha       $.post("altera.php", { checado : '0', id: $(this).val() }, function () { 
      //alert ('selecionado'); 
      
      
      });
      $("#tags").load("conta.php"); coloquei esse .load para chamar esse php que conta os registros e me retorna quantos já foram escolhidos, não sei se é o melhor mas é oque me resolveu

Comment: @PauloJorge parece-me bem, podias colocar uma resposta com isso. Acho que podias fazer essa consula logo quando carregas a página e colocar isso numa variável? Coloca a tua resposta. Se colocares o código do PHP junto também a minha ideia.